# vc++ 2005 linker error

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

I am developing an application in visual studio 2005 (C++) (on windows XP sp2) with the exact same configuration in debug and release mode. The debug mode compiles without errors and run just fine.
The release mode troughs linker errors like the following:

1>Fourrier.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (_*imp*??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z)

I am using opencv 2.0, Qt 4.6, fftw3, and GLC_lib for 3D opengl rendering.

Is there any known issue or have you ever faced this error?

thanks in advance,
Thodoris

Comment: Have you tried setting `/VERBOSE` on your linker command line (Linker → General → Show Progress) for both Debug and Release builds and comparing the results?  Is your Release build definitely searching msvcr80.dll?  (That's where your missing function is exported from.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your linker is not able to find the library dll for the exception class.

Comment: Hi there. thanks for replying. OK, but this isn't it a default visual c++ class coming with the installation of msvc++ 2005?

Comment: yes it is, but somehow your build system is not finding the lib. Try opening the project file in a text editor and carefully comparing the debug config with the release config.

Comment: unfortunately there is no difference.. I should examine each library I link one more time to see what is happening...

Comment: you may have multiple versions of libcpmt.lib on your system. search your system and see. . .

Comment: sometimes you can end up with multiple copies of release libraries but not debug libraries. which libraries are you linking: single-threaded, multithreaded, or multithreaded DLL?

Comment: Yes I have several versions of libcpmt.lib in several folders inside the VC installation as well as a version of the library in visual studio 6 folder.   I also link multithreaded DLL

Comment: ok, if you're using multithreaded DLLs then your default libraries are MSVCRT.LIB and MSVCIRT.LIB for release builds, and MSVCRTD.LIB and MSVCIRTD.LIB for debug builds. You should not have multiple copies of MSVCRT.LIB and MSVCIRT.LIB in your lib paths. Compare the locations and number of MSVCRT.LIB you have with MSVCRTD.LIB. Also, you may be able to choose which MSVCxRT.LIB to use by placing a filepath on the "Additional Dependencies" entry of the "Input" page of the linker config. If you do that, you will need to specify MSVCRT.LIB and MSVCIRT.LIB in "Ignor Specific Default Libaries".

Comment: I have just solved the problem. I removed all the libraries from the path and made a new clean project with the source code and now it works fine. Thanks for the support on!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing any libraries from the Release build that you are including in the Debug build?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.
No I have all the libs also in release mode.